# How to edit bootstrap tab text without it being set as current and functioning?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tabs that are being dynamically created on the fly and am needing to be able to edit any of those tabs text, which I can do. However, I have run into a bit of change to be added and that is being able to edit the tab's text by ctrl+click (which I had done), but, not having the tab be set as current tab.
As an example, I have 5 tabs, the first tab is active, well I want to edit tab 3 without disrupting my currently active tab, by ctrl+click and when done editing that the first tab is still active.

I have two different events happening, one is for the actual click event of a tab

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    if ($('#TabEditorWrapper').hasClass("show-tab-editor")) {
        $('#TabEditorWrapper').removeClass("show-tab-editor");
        $('#SiteOverlay').css('display', 'none');
    }

    ...

    $("#List li").addClass('not-active');
});
```

here is the code that I am using to do an edit when I ctrl+click on a different tab (Yes I know that I have this set up as a click event)

```
$(document).on('click', '#List > .nav-item', function (e) {

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        $(this).find('input').toggle()
            .val($(this)
            .find('a').html()).focus();

        $(this).find('a').toggle();

        oldAreaName = $(this).find("a").text();

        currentAreaID = parseInt($(this).find("a").data('areaid'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your html my guess is if first before your click event find the tab that is currently active. If that tab is not the current tab remove the "active" class from the tab you are editing and reset it to the original one.

Problem is once you click on the tab and the `click` event fires it's to late to get the previous active tab since it has already been clicked so you have to get the current active tab first before you can proceed. You can do this buy creating an event on page load that gets the current active tab

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.nav-link').each( function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var og_active_tab_location = $(this);
        }
    })        
})
```

Now you can tell your click event to remove the class `active` first then mark the og_tab as `active`. It is important to remove the class first before adding it since if the tab you are editing is the same as the original tab then the active class would be removed.

FYI `.nav-link` is located within `.nav-item` and is where the `active` class is applied so you are dealing with `children()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#List > .nav-item', function (e) {

    $(this).children('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
    og_active_tab_location.addClass('active');

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        $(this).find('input').toggle()
            .val($(this)
            .find('a').html()).focus();

        $(this).find('a').toggle();

        oldAreaName = $(this).find("a").text();

        currentAreaID = parseInt($(this).find("a").data('areaid'));
    }

});
```